# Get the time difference in minutes between two timestamps (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, time, domo

Hi I tried the following:

`` timediff(`date2`, `date1`) `` which gives me the time difference but if the days are different it does not account for the day difference. so if date2 is yesterday and date1 is today it will provide something like this: 00:00:07
I saw the timestampdiff function a couple of times, but I am using MySQL in Domo, and this function is not offered there. Any other suggestion how to get the time difference between two timestamps (where days are different) in minutes?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2020-01-07T12:17:03',  '2020-01-06T13:14:02')
```

returns `-1383`

you can change `MINUTE` to  `SECOND` or other formats as well.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

edit: sorry, just read that the function is not available in your environment...

therefore I suggets to convert the datetimes to seconds and work your way up from there, e.g.

```sql
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-07T12:17:03') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-06T13:14:02')) / 60
```